# WSO2AM REST API: refresh application subscribtion accessToken

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have application that communicate with WSO2AM 2.1.0 using their Restful API.

Right now I'm working on the application subscription part, I need to create a feature that able to refresh `accessToken`, it's the `keys[0].token.accessToken` from json below.

```
GET https://localhost:9443/api/am/store/v0.11/applications/896658a0-b4ee-4535-bbfa-806c894a4015
Authorization: Bearer ae4eae22-3f65-387b-a171-d37eaa366fa8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "groupId": "",
   "callbackUrl": null,
   "subscriber": "admin",
   "throttlingTier": "Unlimited",
   "applicationId": "896658a0-b4ee-4535-bbfa-806c894a4015",
   "description": null,
   "status": "APPROVED",
   "name": "DefaultApplication",
   "keys": [   {
      "consumerKey": "AVoREWiB16kY_GTIzscl40GYYZQa",
      "consumerSecret": "KXQxmS8W3xDvvJH4AfR6xrhKIeIa",
      "keyState": "COMPLETED",
      "keyType": "PRODUCTION",
      "supportedGrantTypes": null,
      "token":       {
         "validityTime": 3600,
         "accessToken": "3887da6d111f0429c6dff47a46e87209",
         "tokenScopes":          [
            "am_application_scope",
            "default"
         ]
      }
   }]
}
```

I ended up reading this documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API and I think that is not the documentation I'm searching for. The token API there is used to refresh the access token to the WSO2, not for refreshing the application subscribtion token.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store API uses client-credential grant type to generate an access token. That is why you don't get the refresh token in the response. You can do the following.

Used the API - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/

1. Create an application in APIM Store. (/applications)
2. Get consumerKey and consumer secret of the application by generating the keys. (/applications/generate-keys)

Use the password grant type and generate a token. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Password+Grant